# Как сделать разворачивающийся список с кастомными элементами?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть recyclerView, мне надо к каждому из его элементов прикрепить **разворачивающийся** список из элементов, которые состоят из textView, button и checkBox. Что мне использовать, чтобы это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой на мой взгляд вариант - сделать свою разметку для каждого элемента родительского списка и разворачивать ее при нажатии на кнопку. Например делаем такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/expandClick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
            android:contentDescription="exp_btn_tag" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hiddenLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/old_item"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relLay">

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Здесь есть элемент `relLay` это будет ваш видимый контент, вы здесь размещаете ваш кружочек и textView. Так же есть `expandClick` - здесь расположена кнопка при нажатии на которую вы раскрываете ваш элемент. И соответственно `hiddenLayout` - это будет контейнер для вашего скрытого списка. Сюда вы помещаете ваш второй recyclerView. Дальше в адаптере прописываем действие на клик по кнопке показа:

```
holder.frameLayout.setOnClickListener {
   if (invisible) {
       holder.layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       invisible = false
       holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_arrow)
   } else {
     holder.layout.visibility = View.GONE
     invisible = true
     holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow)
   }
}
```

В функции клика вам нужно будет загрузить данные в список. Есть так же библиотеки для реализации того что вам нужно, например [эта](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view).